# Making a message return all the database rows

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am fairly new to node.js / discord.js and I am attempting to make a system that gets the rows from a database and returns all the rows in a SINGLE message.

I currently have it working returning a message for every row, but this obviously isn't practical

This is my current code:

````
con.query("SELECT * FROM bans", function(err, rows) {
        rows.forEach(function(row) {
            console.log(row.user)
            message.channel.send("```" + row.user + "```")
        });
    })
````

Comment: Have a look at structuring your message via json or xml to make it easier to generate and parse. But you need to be careful about the volume of data you are passing around, how many rows are there on your database table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this:

````
con.query("SELECT * FROM bans", function(err, rows) {
            message.channel.send("```" + rows.map(row => row.user).join('\n') + "```")
        });
````